# Valid domain rejected by James

Tags: smtp, james, apache-james

For some reason suddenly I’m getting that error on James:

```
DEBUG 09:32:35,635 | james.smtpserver | Id='1973954440' User='' Unknown domain ABC  so reject it
DEBUG 09:32:35,635 | james.smtpserver | Id='1973954440' User='' executing hook org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.log.HookResultLogger@340c2af4
DEBUG 09:32:35,635 | james.smtpserver | Id='1973954440' User='' org.apache.james.smtpserver.fastfail.ValidRcptHandler: result=8 (DECLINED)
```

Any clue what is wrong that valid domain is getting rejected?

Comment: **Why** do you caim the domain is valid?

Comment: @AnFi Valid = known at least was working before ;) Anyway I'm close to have it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came up that vHost was not translated on the firewall to allowed address in the `smtpserver.conf` so I have added that vHost IP there plus mapped it on the firewall to correct internal IP which existed already in the `smtpserver.conf`